# Is it possible to restrict Google OAuth login to a specific user?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I have a web application in React and I'm currently using Clerk for connections, that works fine for Simple Email/Password and Google connections.

Now, I want to only have Google connection with the "Sign In With Google" button, **but I want it to work with only my account.** The web app should be publicly accessible but only my account should be able to log in. How should I proceed ? The web app would only use the Google Sheet API.

(If I can keep Clerk that's fine but if I have to use native OAuth implementation of Google's services, that's also fine)

I've searched multiple topics (on SO or on other websites), but their use cases is only for a specific domain or a specific group of user. I only want to use my account with the comfort of Google authentication.

Answer (score 1):

This is an authentication v authorization question. It is similar to many corporate setups where only administrator approved employees are authorized.

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER ROLE**

Usually in OAuth you use an authorization server (AS) that enables an administrator to create pre-approved user accounts, eg in an `accounts` table. In your case this would be just you. After login the AS issues OAuth tokens that best suit your APIs and apps.

**IDENTITY PROVIDER ROLE**

The sign in with Google option is an authentication method and Google usually has an IDP role. You can't stop people with a Google account from authenticating since you don't control that system.

**POST AUTHENTICATION ACTIONS**

After Google sign in completes, the AS can run an action to check that the user exists in the accounts table and deny access otherwise.

If you are not using an AS and are integrating with Google directly, you would have to do this at the application level instead.